# Como utilizar WITH LOCK do Firebird com o FireDac do Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-7, firedac, delphi-10

Estou tentando **Bloquear** uma tabela no meu sistema com o intuito de impedir que outros usuários entrem no sistema quando o procedimento estiver sendo executado, como posso fazer isso utilizado o **"WITH LOCK"** com o **"FireDac"**?

- Esse comendo bloqueia a tabela para gravação ou também bloqueia para *visualização*?
- Caso bloqueie para *visualização* e *gravação*, como utilizar corretamente?
- Como identificar via Delphi que a tabela ou registro está travado?

Comment: Estou Utilizando Delphi 10.1 para escrever esse sistema com Firebird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de Tanto Tentar eu resolvi a questão.
Para poder funcionar no `FireDac` terá que desativar o **AutoCommit** ex: `FDConnection1.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;`.

- **P** - Esse comendo bloqueia a tabela para gravação ou também bloqueia para
  visualização?
- **R** - O Comando **WITH LOCK** bloqueia as linhas que serão trazidas em uma instrução `SQL` como o @Lucas de Souza Cruz disse. ex: `SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE FIELD1=VALUE WITH LOCK` e desbloqueia quando um comando `COMMIT` ou `ROLLBACK` o comando `WITH LOCK` não bloqueia para visualização.
- **P** - Caso bloqueie para visualização e gravação, como utilizar corretamente?
- **R** - O Comando **WITH LOCK** bloqueia apenas para Gravação como foi dito acima e não bloqueia para visualização.
- **P** - Como identificar via Delphi que a tabela ou registro está travado?
- **R** - Para testar basta tentar inserir ou editar a tabela se apresentar uma mensagem tipo assim:

> execution caused by system error that does not preclude successful
>   execution of subsequent statements. Lock conflict on no wait
>   transaction.

A linha da tabela está bloqueada. Você pode fazer tratamento de exceções para evitar mensagem em inglês... Vai da imaginação de cada.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei [nessa documentação do FireBird](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-notes-withlock.html), a forma correta de utilizar esse comando. A documentação fala sobre alguns cuidados ao usar esse comando. Pelo que li na documentação, ele retorna uma linha comprometida caso a mesma utilize o `WITH LOCK`.

Li em alguns fóruns não oficias do Firebird que as linhas são automaticamente 
"liberadas" ao realizar um `commit` ou `rollback` na transação. Ou seja, ele não trava a tabelas, mas sim as linhas que estiveram no `SQL` do `WITH LOCK` executado.

Infelizmente não tenho muita experiência no Firebird, então, de certa forma, é muito complicado dizer todos os impactos da utilização deste comando em sua aplicação. Talvez, como solução de contorno e de menos impacto no seu sistema e banco de dados, utilizar uma `flag` dentro do banco de dados (em uma tabela de parâmetros, por exemplo) deixaria o processo mais simplificado.

Por exemplo: se essa coluna estiver como `TRUE`, o sistema retornaria uma mensagem alegando que não está pronto para conexão, pois está passando por um processo de atualização.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou muito Obrigado!